# Teamcity agent in disconnected state (Agent has unregistered (will upgrade))

Tags: teamcity

Teamcity build agent in disconnected state (Agent has unregistered (will upgrade)) on the server UI.
The build agent service was in hung state tried reboot but still didn't work so manually upgraded the TC build agent with the version server had. Rebooted the build agent service. Still disconnected. Please suggest.

Comment: Take a look in the upgrade log of the build agent to see if it gives any information https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Viewing+Build+Agent+Logs

Comment: Checked the logs there were some files in /work and /system that weren't getting deleted. Forced deleted to them and it took the upgrade. Thanks!

Comment: Check build agent properties file on the server and make sure the token value is correct.

Answer (score 20):

I ran into this issue and found a solution, but I'm going to make a few assumptions about your setup.

This fixed an issue I had with a TeamCity build agent on Windows and running as a user account (as opposed to a System Account).

1. Stopped the TeamCity service and changed the account to a System Account
2. Started the TeamCity service and waited about 10 minutes for the upgrade to complete.  The build agent showed up in the "Connected" agents tab indicating a successful upgrade.
3. Stopped the TeamCity service and switched back to the user account
4. Started the TeamCity service

The other option is to grant the user account permissions to start/stop services, but I went this route instead.  See [this article](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Setting+up+and+Running+Additional+Build+Agents#SettingupandRunningAdditionalBuildAgents-NecessaryOSandenvironmentpermissions) for those steps.

Comment: I had to change both server and agent's account to make it connected.

Answer (score 8):

Old question but someone might find my comments useful. If you cant read the upgrade logs, check the `buildAgent/update/` folder, If files and files sizes are changing in this particular folder then It means that the Agent is updating and you only need to wait. If this is not the case but you still see `Agent has unregistered (will upgrade)` in Team city under *Agents* --> *Disconnected* then the agent is either hung or there is some problem with it. Stop the agent from the services and then by running the `agent.bat`(Windows) and `agent.sh` (nix) by giving `stop` argument and then start it from the same script using `start` argument. You can also see the status of the agent using `status` argument. If this also does not work then you will have to read all the logs.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

1. In the Agents tab, I removed the build agent by clicking "Remove Agent".
2. I restarted the service.
3. I refreshed the Agents tab and it the build agent appeared in the Unauthorized Agents.
4. I authorized the agent and it's now connected.

Answer (score 2):

For the one who kept restarting build agent service and see the "Agent has unregistered(will upgrade)", please check the log under BuildAgent/logs to see the upgrade process and wait.

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this problem too on Ubuntu Linux 19.10 and it is related to systemd. My TeamCity agents are started and stopped using a systemd script and apparently this is what prevents them from upgrading. When I stopped teamcity systemd services and started agents manually with `agent.sh start` agents successfully updated and worked just fine since that.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the service user did not fix the issue for me :
but this method worked (Windows, with Teamcity server and agents on the same machine).

1. Stop these services : Teamcity server, all the Teamcity agents.
2. Open a `cmd.exe` instance as Administrator.
3. Run these (adapt to you own paths / number of agents). It will start Teamcity server and agents as simple processes (i.e. not as services) :

```
cd C:\Teamcity\bin
.\runAll.bat start
cd C:\Teamcity\BuildAgent1\bin
.\agent.bat start
cd C:\Teamcity\BuildAgent2\bin
.\agent.bat start
cd C:\Teamcity\BuildAgent3\bin
.\agent.bat start
```

4. Check in the UI that the agents have registered again.
5. Kill the processes created in `3.` ; and start the Teamcity services again.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. (TeamCity 2023.05.)

Answer (score 1):

It could be the permissions on the account under which the agent is running. In BuildAgent\Logs\Upgrade.txt, you may find this

*Upgrade failed: Failed to stop TeamCity build agent service. Please check TeamCity build agent service user have enough permissions to stop and start the service. 
java.io.IOException: Failed to stop TeamCity build agent service. Please check TeamCity build agent service user have enough permissions to stop and start the service.*

Although the service appears to be running fine on the machine (windows in my case), it produces the error in it's log rather than event viewer or failing to start,  and disconnects from TeamCity on upgrade.

I gave higher privileges and it started to work. +1 to Lemtronix's way if you do not want to restrict permissions of your service account.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I triggered a build and the agent was automatically changed to **connected** status.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the agent tries to upgrade itself, but if your Windows service is set up running from non-admin account, it fails.
Options are:

- Temporary change service account to System as proposed by @Lemtronix
- Add user to administrators group and restart service.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue with `TeamCity 2019.2.4` on `Windows Server 2016` by completing the following steps listed below:

1. **Stop** the `TeamCity Build Agent` service.
2. **Stop** the `TeamCity Server` service.
3. **Start** the `TeamCity Server` service.
4. **Start** the `TeamCity Build Agent` service.
5. Refresh the TeamCity UI tab in your browser window, and wait a few moments for the status to reflect `Connected` in green.